# How to prevent the Chrome Default Browser Prompt and Welcome Screen Using Master Preferences file?

Tags: deployment, google-chrome, json, chrome

I am attempting to deploy Chrome and have followed Jay Michaud's guide found [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/635202/how-can-i-customize-the-default-settings-when-deploying-google-chrome-for-busine/635203).

I have created my JSON file corresponding to Chrome's most recent provided information on doing so found in the links provided in Jay's guide. I minify/compact my JSON and run it through JSLint and everything checks out as fine. I then proceed with the Windows Installer Transform operation and, after doing this, attempt to install Chrome in my Dev VM. Chrome installs successfully, however, upon opening Chrome the second time, I am greeted with the Welcome Screen requesting sign-in. Upon opening Chrome the third time I am greeted with the ever annoying "Make Chrome your default browser" bar. I'm at a complete loss on 1) How to prevent the Welcome Screen, and 2) How to prevent the Default Browser Check. My JSON is available here on PasteBin: [Chrome Master Preferences File](https://pastebin.com/KVmBNrfX)

Additionally, here is an install log: [Chrome Install Log](https://pastebin.com/Xa5AbAZt)

My primary object is to at least get rid of the default browser prompt. I can deal with the welcome screen, but it would be nice to forego it as well. Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Note that I have tried creating the First One File in `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data`, but that doesn't work either. Also note that my plan is to deploy this via Intune, so I have some limited ADMX capabilities for managing Google Chrome, but nothing to prevent icon creation as well as a handful of other things. Thought I'd deploy Google Chrome via the Win32 App method after having used a transform operation as a result of Intune's limited capabilities.

Comment: Ok. I seem to have figured out how to prevent the Default Browser notification. By adding the "default_browser_infobar_last_declined": "randomnumberhere" and "should_reset_check_default_browser": false JSON entries, I'm no longer receiving it. I pulled both these from the Preferences file found in %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default. I also just grabbed the number for default_browser_infobar_last_declined from that file as well. I figure that number is representative of specific time in the past. Neither of these are mentioned in the Chromium documentation that I can find...

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Got both of these figured out. To copy my comment from above concerning the Default Browser notification:

> Ok. I seem to have figured out how to prevent the Default Browser notification. By adding the "default_browser_infobar_last_declined": "randomnumberhere" and "should_reset_check_default_browser": false JSON entries, I'm no longer receiving it. I pulled both these from the Preferences file found in %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default. I also just grabbed the number for default_browser_infobar_last_declined from that file as well. I figure that number is representative of specific time in the past.

This will remove the Default App bar across the upper part of the Chrome window.

In Intune itself, you can simply create a Configuration Profile -> W10 -> Settings Catalog -> Admin Template -> Google -> Google Chrome and then set the `Enable showing full-tab promotional content` to *disabled*.

The [Chrome Enterprise Policy documentation page](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/) is very helpful as it has a more full-scale search capability than Intune does. It effectively has the capability to search through the tooltips in Intune, so you can find keywords relating to the policy(ies) you are search for. In my case, I searched for "welcome."